# How do I move Godot 4 Control nodes so they don't expand drastically?

Tags: user-interface, godot, gdscript

I am making a pixel-art card game in Godot 4, that has a 2d UI on top of a 3d space. The idea is to have the Cards rendered in the UI portion, with 10 card templates (the maximum hand size) prerendered off-screen. When I need to add one to the hand, I am trying to add all of the relevant data to the template, and then move it on screen. However, when I do so, the card expands to be several times larger than I have it set as when it is off screen. Does anyone know the cause of this?

See Images below for more details, I can give more as needed.

[image]

This is the UI with the 3d space rendered behind it.

[image]

This is what happens on execution, the card is expanded massively.

[image]

This is the code I use to populate the data and move it onscreen. I am using the card's global position to move it.

I have tried using the scale properties of the card as well as manually changing the card's properties in the Node editor, neither of which seem to be working.

Comment: Guess it`s not that easy to say, without more infos. What does your populating function do exactly? 

What you could try to do is to set the card size again after populating the card. Controlnodes resize to fit their new content, so this could be the reason they expand, after you change the content.

Comment: It seems like manually changing the size works! Thanks for the suggestion!